# Provider 'MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' has been denied when executing stored procedure from ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel, import

I've been looking all around for a fix, but I cannot find it.

Basically I setup a stored procedure in sql server that reads an excel file into a table. I managed to make it work inside SQL Server Management Studio. But when I try to execute it inside a webpage I get the error:

> Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' has been
>   denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.

Things I've tried include running the following commands:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO
```

I've also tried giving access to the temp folder of SQL Server to my SQL user.

I've been running in circles for a while... here is the relevant SQL code that runs fine inside management studio:

```
set @q = 'INSERT INTO #RDV_BUFFER (noDossier,RDVDate,Facturation,debut,fin,debutreel,finreel,MinutesParUnites) SELECT nodos, daterdv, montfact, heuredebut, heurefin,heureassis,heureleve,horstep FROM OPENROWSET(''MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Excel 8.0; Database=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ProDentaireElite\XLS_Root\' + @URL + '; HDR=YES; IMEX=1'', ''SELECT * FROM [' + @Sheetname + '$]'')'

EXEC sp_executesql @q
```

Thanks to all the gurus out there. Maybe your knowledge can help.

Comment: Additional info: I'm running windows 10, with office 2010 installed (x64), sql server is also x64 and version 12

Comment: The following post over on DBA suggests that you will also need to change a registry setting: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61739/help-with-sql-server-error-ad-hoc-access-to-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oled

Comment: Thanks! I manually added the key in the registry and now I get a new error: Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it, there were 2 "Temp" folders I needed to give access to my SQL User. One located in the windows microsoft sql server folder, and the other, located in my own user. Make sure you set them up to ''Full control'' or it won't work.