# PyODBC + MS SQL Server + OPENROWSET to read/join Excel table with database table not working through PyODBC

Tags: sql-server, excel, permissions, pyodbc, openrowset

I'm working on an ETL that needs to join a user's Excel spreadsheet with one of our database tables in order to get the Latitude Longitude and return it to our users. For maintainability, I want a pipeline where a DB query does basically all the table work, rather than code, because then I can create a system where non-programmer analysts can patch together similar solutions by rewriting the query.

My proof-of-concept query (below/bottom) works in SQL Server Management Studio, but I've been unable to get it working through a PyODBC connection. Of note: *PyODBC is connecting with the same user that can perform this query in SQL Management Studio*. I'm getting the error (emphasis mine)..

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]**Cannot
> initialize the data source** object of OLE DB provider
> "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" **for linked server "(null)"**. (7303)
> (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for
> linked server "(null)" returned message **"Failure creating file."**.
> (7412)')

I've Googled this every way I can think of. There's a [RegEdit trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644978/ad-hoc-access-to-ole-db-provider-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-has-been-denied-you/55645237) that didn't work or change the error. Another promising lead required [giving some users' temp folder permissions to the 'Everyone' user and applying full control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33131833). I've tried this on several different user accounts to no effect and no change. But it's possible I'm not getting the right accounts or the right temp folders..

It seems like PyODBC connects in a way that is off limits to `OPENROWSET` > `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` driver AND/OR, the context of this connection is unable to access/read the file location. For now, I've made sure the file location is accessible to 'Everyone' with Full Control enabled.

One more note, I've reduced this back to `SELECT * FROM FROM OPENROWSET(/*params*/)` and it throws the same error, so I'm certain the issue is exclusive to this `OpenRowSet` approach.

I don't have a super-specific question beyond "Does anyone have any additional ideas why this isn't working?" Alternatively, if there is a different way to execute this query in a scripted environment other than Python/PyODBC I'd be interested in that option too! Thanks

```
 select 
      /* THEIR TABLE DATA */
      d."civic number", 
      d."street name", 
      d."road type", 
      /* OUR SPATIAL DATA TABLE */
      a.FULLADDRESS,
      a.STATUS,
      a.SHAPE.STAsText() as wkt
      /* THEIR EXCEL TABLE RESOURCE */
      FROM OPENROWSET(
        ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
        ''Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Users\GeoTASKS\ETL\addresses.xlsx'',
        ''select * from [sheet1$]'') d 
      /* OUR DATABASE RESOURCE */
      join gis.ADDRESS_POINTS a
        on CONCAT(
                UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(d."civic number"))), '' '',  
                UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(d."street name"))), '' '', 
                UPPER(sde.RCGeoAbbreviateRoadType(d."road type"))
        ) = upper(a.fulladdress)
      where UPPER(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.STATUS))) = ''FINAL''
```

Comment: Ok, it's looking like [the Microsoft-native `sqlcmd` utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files?view=sql-server-ver15) might be able to do what I'm wanting here ..possibly even a bit cleaner. I was able to get the query to run over command line, so the next step is to find a way to use it in the context I have in mind.

Comment: There's a lot going on here. Python & Excel play well together, Python and SQL Server play well together, and Excel and SQL Server play well together. To do a 3-way seems somewhat unorthodox. What's your end-game here? What do you really want to do?

Comment: I want an automation to run a stored procedure or a view that can join a user's Excel sheet on existing database tables, where the query itself also sets the output schema (column names, datatypes, value defaults). The Python is just glue for a few less complicated aspects, which could be handled with shell commands, but which would be cleaner in Python. But another issue I've ran into is that `OPENROWSET()` doesn't seem to allow parameterization of the file name as a value for a stored procedure. I can get around that though. Of course, I'm interested in suggestions for a better strategy.